# Google review widget for web-application | write google review using google place api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, dialogflow-es, google-widget

**I created a review portal for my customers to give me a review and ratings on my service via different social networking sites.**

Currently I am focusing on **google review** to be collected via a google widget/flow,

[image: The website containing all the social networking review link for my business]

This above image is showing the available list of social networking sites to give review. please **skip the Facebook i already integrated that**.

***When the user clicks "google", the google review dialog will be shown on the page to collect the google review.(Image is mentioned bellow)***

I would like to avoid people from going away from my website.

I would like to know how to use google.places.reviews.createPublishReviewFlow for writing Google review via Google review widget. I saw this API Widget service has been used by some websites/web applications

[image]

I want some documentation/code/sample any thing which is helpful.

Comment: I'm confused. How is this related to dialogflow, google-maps, or the google-places-api?

Comment: don't get confused all i want is to collect the user review and rating without redirecting him to google domain.

Comment: What is wrong with just directing them to google domain to write the review? using review link like [this](https://support.google.com/business/answer/7035772?hl=en)

Comment: No I don't do this because after collecting the user's feedback I have to redirect the user to some other page.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? What was the solution?

Comment: @NiteshShaw can you give the example of how you have integrated facebook and google both?

Comment: @Aslam Actually these two buttons are link button, when user click the link user is redirected to separate pages to write review in google and write review in facebook.

Comment: @NiteshShaw were you able to create something like the image above? I have been trying the same for almost 1 week now. But I am unable to make it work. If you get anything please let me know also. Thank You! yunus.aslam@gmail.com

Comment: this is an google review widget but this API is obsoleted now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use http://getreviewlink.com/ to generate a link for your customers to leave reviews at for Google. This only works for Google.

Answer (score -1):

You could use an iframe.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

You just have to replace the src value by the right one. The only fear that I have about this technique is that you probably want to know when the user posted his review ; but you can't interact with an iframe (with jquery for example) so you'll not be able to know when the user validate the form.

Comment: Cant render the page in iframe because frame-origin header is not allowing.